# How to parse a json field that may be a string and may be an array with Jackson

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson, deserialization

I have a json field that is string when there's one value:

```
{ "theField":"oneValue" }
```

or array when there are multiple values:

```
{ "theField": [ "firstValue", "secondValue" ] }
```

And then I have my java class that uses com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator:

```
public class TheClass { 
    private final List<String> theField;

    @JsonCreator
    public TheClass(@JsonProperty("theField") List<String> theField) {
        this.theField = theField;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the code does not work when the incoming field is string. The exception thrown is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
```

And if I change it to expect string it throws the similar exception against an array...

I'd appreciate any ideas on what should I use instead of @JsonCreator or how to make it work with both types of field

Thanks in advance,
Stan Kilaru

Comment: Hmm and I guess it's not possible to replace the string with an array containing one string in the case of one value, right?

Comment: I can't modify the incoming JSON - it's thirdparty thing :(

Comment: Did you try with `@JsonProperty("theField")` Object?

Comment: Then you could do something like
    `try {
        this.theField = (List<String>) theField
    } catch (CastException e) {
        this.theField = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.theField.add(theField);
    }`

Comment: Making your `theField` an Object instead of a specific type, will work. I just tried here. The problem is you will have to do some type verification to use the field later on.

Comment: @dambros great! Thanks! This approach works!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try the following:

```
public class TheClass { 
    private final List<String> theField;

    @JsonCreator
    public TheClass(@JsonProperty("theField") Object theField) {
        if (theField instanceof ArrayList) {
            this.theField = theField;
        } else {
            this.theField = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.theField.add(theField);
        }
    }
}
```