# How to deserialize JSON to class Object in java

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, jackson

I am using the Jackson library to convert from JSON to Class Object, but the problem is when the answer can be string or array, for example:

data throws a message:

```
{
   "status":"OK",
   "data": "No results"
}
```

data releases an array:

```
{
   "status":"OK",
   "data":[
      {
         "a":"190923114052",
         "b":"",
         "c":"1176225-19"
      }
   ]
}
```

My class

```
public class ReponseWS(){
    private String status;
    private List<Data> data;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

When data comes as string and not as array

**Error:** Could not read JSON: Cannot deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token

I hope to help me thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse a json field that may be a string and may be an array with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330226/how-to-parse-a-json-field-that-may-be-a-string-and-may-be-an-array-with-jackson)

Comment: @vilpe89 I'm just consuming API

Comment: @Tarmo It is indeed the same question, however you cannot solve the problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can register `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler` and implement `handleUnexpectedToken` method. In case expected type is `ArrayList` and `JsonToken` is `VALUE_STRING` you can always return new `ArrayList` object:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
        .addHandler(new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext ctxt, JavaType targetType, JsonToken t, JsonParser p, String failureMsg) throws IOException {
                if (targetType.getRawClass() == ArrayList.class && t == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
                    return new ArrayList<>();
                }
                return super.handleUnexpectedToken(ctxt, targetType, t, p, failureMsg);
            }
        })
        .build();
```

Comment: Thank you all very much, you solved the problem by customizing the json to the correct way.